# 20:13 aspect ratio in beamer

Tags: beamer, paper-size

Guy Steele argues that when you don’t know whether to expect a 4:3 or a 16:9 projector, [you should use 20:13 as the aspect ratio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HKbjYqqPPQ).

But `beamer` supports only a fixed set of aspect ratios via the `aspectratio=` options, and 20:13 is not one of them.

How can I still produce beamer slides with a 20:13 aspect ratio?

Comment: Make a feature request that the option is added.

Comment: I guess I should – but that doesn’t help me with the talk in one week :-)

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/497

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding

```
\makeatletter
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{20.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{13.00cm}%
    \geometry{papersize={\beamer@paperwidth,\beamer@paperheight}}
\makeatother
```

should do the job, though it might be necessary to tweak the overall scale here.

Comment: Thanks! Went with `15.38cm/10cm` for now.